# Pest identification on Fuyu Persimmon tree

Tags: diagnosis, pests, fungus, persimmon

My persimmon tree has been struggling for 2 seasons in the CA Bay Area. The leaves have been turning brown at the tips, eventually turning black and falling off. I’ve tried some copper fungicide applications to no avail. I also noticed that this is affecting new and old growth, but not evenly distributed across the tree.

I’ve noticed these fuzzy things on the underside of the dying parts. I’ve assumed they were fruiting bodies but I noticed these small insects. Anyone know what might be infecting the plant?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps powdery mildew, but I am not sure. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Symptoms-of-powdery-mildew-of-sweet-persimmon-caused-by-Phyllactinia-kakicola-Symptoms_fig1_273208412